# Which word should I use "which" or "where"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which one of the two following sentences is correct?

> It's a place which they can call home.

Or

> It's a place where they can call home.

I'm asking this question because I recently wrote a paragraph in which I used the word "which" but my teacher changed it to "where" and I was wondering why? Why did she did that?

Comment: Technically, neither is necessary. "It's a place they can call home" is perfectly fine. If you really want to use which/where don't forget that "that" is an option, too.

Comment: @Catija - I think some might argue that "that" would be a _better_ option. [More here](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaClauses__Restrictive_and_Nonrest.htm).

Comment: Ok guys I understand I asked this question because I recently wrote a paragraph in which I used the word "which" and my teacher changed it to "where" and I thought why? Why did she changed it?

Comment: That context is really important to your question because it helps us understand why you're asking. Please [edit] that information into your question and consider including similar context in future questions!

Comment: @AlanCarmack I like "which" better than "where" and "there" "there" doesn't rhyme in my sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They mean different things.

> It's a place which they can call home.

is the same as

> It's a place that they can call home.

It says that they consider the place to be their home.

You can also use

> It is a place they can call home

for the same meaning.

---

On the other hand,

> It's a place where they can call home.

means that when they are in the place, then they can call home - e.g. because there is a phone they can use to do it.

Comment: The Marx Brothers film *Animal Crackers* has a joke about this ambiguity. "'...just a little place that I can call home and tell the wife I won't be there for dinner.' 'I see, you just want a telephone booth.'" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eW-NK0aVQg

Answer (score 1):

Relative pronouns *that* and *which* can be used interchangeably in most circumstances. When used as object relative pronouns, as in the sentence 1, they are often left out of the sentence altogether. Delete "where" from the second, and it'll be correct too - unless you really meant making phone calls, not calling the place their home.

Comment: This is true, but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, a place is a where. 
Which: what one or ones of a group : what particular one or ones — used to indicate what is being shown, pointed to, or mentioned (dictionary)

Comment: Your answer is actually incorrect. I understand how you reason, but it is still incorrect. Please read the accepted answer, for a better explanation.